# Allowing user to reset a list... but also allowing them to restore the deleted list?

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a Todo list for practice and was wondering if there was a way to restore a list. I was thinking of creating a copy of the list and then re-adding the contents to the DOM once the user hits a restore 'Restore List' button but I just can't figure it out!

Here is my current code, the button appears when I hit 'Reset List' button but it is not functional yet.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {  

  //Targets the unordered list element
  const list = document.getElementById("myUL");
  //Targets the children of the unordered list
  const li = list.children;

  const resetDiv = document.getElementById('resetPanel');
  const resetButton = document.createElement('button');
  const restoreButton = document.createElement('button');
  restoreButton.textContent = 'Restore Items';
  resetButton.textContent = 'Reset List';
  resetDiv.appendChild(resetButton);

  //Targets the form element.
  const form = document.getElementById("registrar");

  //Function declaration (Begins process of creating list item)
  function createListItem(text){
    //Creates the list item
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    //Function delcaration (creates an element and returns element)
    function createElement(elementName, property, value) {
      const element = document.createElement(elementName);
      element[property] = value;
      return element;
    }

    //Function declaration (Adds the created element to the list)
    function appendToLi(elementName, property, value){
      const element = createElement(elementName, property, value);
      li.appendChild(element);
      return element;
    }

      //Appends all children to the list item.
      appendToLi('span', 'textContent', text);
      appendToLi('label', 'textContent', 'Completed')
        .appendChild(createElement('input', 'type', 'checkbox'));
      appendToLi('button', 'textContent', 'remove');
      appendToLi('button', 'textContent', 'edit');

      /*Returns the list item and it's children to what has called the
      createListItem function*/
      return li;
  }

  //Sets an event listener to the reset button.
  resetButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
      const listCopy = document.getElementById("myUL");


      //Moves through the unordered list and removes each list item.
      while (ul.firstChild) {
        ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
      }
    resetDiv.appendChild(restoreButton);
  });

  //This button should restore the removed list items. ***********************
  restoreButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    resetDiv.removeChild(restoreButton);
  });



    //Event listener (listens for click on submit button/enter press)
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      //Targets the input element.
      const input = document.querySelector('input');

      //If the user has not entered any text in the  input field, alerts.
      if(input.value === '') {
        alert('Please enter an item!');

      //Otherise begins the process of creating the list item.
      } else {

        //Holds the user text input.
        const text = input.value;

        /*Calls the createListItem function which will begin the process
          through various other functions.*/
        const listItem = createListItem(text);
        list.appendChild(listItem);
        input.value = '';
      }

  });

  //Listens for clicks on the list item's children buttons.
  list.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const button = e.target;
    const li = e.target.parentNode;
    const ul = li.parentNode;

    //Click on remove button
    if(button.textContent === 'remove'){
      ul.removeChild(li);  

    //Click on edit button
    } else if (button.textContent === 'edit'){
      const span = li.firstElementChild;
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.type = 'text';
      input.value = span.textContent;

      //Inserts a text field in place of the previous span item (User's input)
      li.insertBefore(input, span);
      li.removeChild(span);
      button.textContent = 'save';

    //Click on save button
    } else if (button.textContent === 'save'){
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      const input = li.firstElementChild;
      span.textContent = input.value;

      //Inserts the new text over the input field.
      li.insertBefore(span, input);
      li.removeChild(input);
      button.textContent = 'edit';
    }

  });


});
```

Comment: Try to post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you wanna do u obviously have to save deleted items into a cache but copying d whole thing wont be efficient (it would work maybe with a bit more code) try placing d deleted item into an array list with d position iD on d initial list and putting d item back u could just put it back at the initial position and if d id is a numbering system that helps with position you could just add 1 to all d items after d previously deleted item

Comment: Damn, so it's a bit more confusing than I thought. I was going to try and just set another item to the current lists children but it doesn't work. Such as newList.children = oldList.children;